# How to limit Firebase database persistence store to only some nodes?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, persistence

Adding the following code to the `AppDelegate` will make the Firebase database available when the user is off-line:

```
FIRDatabase.database().persistenceEnabled = true
```

How can we make just some parts of the database available in off-line mode and some parts available just when the user is on-line?

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: *you can't*. Firebase don't currently provide such a fine grained persistence scope API.

What you can do instead is decrease/increase the amount of disk space used by the persistence cache. By default, it will use up to *10MB* of disk space to cache data (a small amount by today standards, by the way). This is controlled by the [`FIRDatabase.persistenceCacheSizeBytes`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/ios/firebasedatabase/api/reference/Classes/FIRDatabase#persistencecachesizebytes) property.

For instance, using a *larger* cache might hold more nodes from your desired subset... if you are lucky :)

Conversely, a smaller value might affect your network performance/cost in significant ways.

Comment: I'd highly recommend against changing the disk size for this purpose.